# ansible with_first_found not working

Tags: shell, variables, ansible

I have this part of a playbbok

```
- shell: echo "{{ ansible_env.CMS_PLI }}/conf/application.conf"
  register: pli_loc
- shell: echo "{{ ansible_env.CMS }}/conf/application.conf"
  register: cms_loc
- shell: "echo {{ item }}"
  with_first_found:
    - "{{ pli_loc.stdout }}"
    - "{{ cms_loc.stdout }}"
    - "{{ ansible_env.CMS_PLI }}/conf/application.conf"
    - /etc/passwd
```

First and second shell output are ok, the files exist but the third shell outputs only /etc/passwd

I would like the third shell output to be one of pli_loc.stdout or cms_loc.stdout

Why doesn't it find one of the first ones?

Comment: Stick a call to the `debug:` module before the last shell command to make sure those values contain what you think they contain.  Does running in verbose mode yield any additional information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why doesn't it find one of the first ones?

Because `with_first_found` (like all lookup plugins) are executed locally, not remotely. So you're looking for files on the control host.

Have a look at the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html#selecting-files-and-templates-based-on-variables) for that loop. The example is a template task, so it's clear it's searching on the control host. Unfortunately the docs are not very clear in that matter and you have to read it in the context of the used modules.